# Is there a way to return asset data along with entry data?

Tags: elementcriteriamodel, plugin-elementapi

I'm using the Element API plugin to return data from an entry that also contains an image asset. Is there a way to combine the two so I can get the asset URL alongside the entry fields?

Attached below is an approximation of my line of thinking.

```
        'elementType' => 'Entry',
        'criteria' => ['section' => 'wax'],

        'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
            return [
                'excerpt' => $entry->excerpt,
                'heroImage' => $asset->heroImage.url // Something like this?
            ];
```

Comment: So the asset field is a custom field on the entry?

Answer (score 4):

Yes - you can access it exactly the same way you do in the templates; you just need to use PHP syntax (e.g. `->` for accessing sub-properties rather than `.`).

```php
'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
    // Begin defining the response data for this entry
    $data = [
        'excerpt' => $entry->excerpt,
    ];

    // Get the first asset in a "heroImage" Assets field (if there is one)
    $heroImage = $entry->heroImage->first();

    if ($heroImage) {
        $data['heroImage'] = $heroImage->url;
    }

    return $data;
})
```

Comment: Hi Brandon, works a charm. Thanks, and thanks for the stellar software!